# Select statement involving SET data type

Tags: mysql, select

How to use the `SET` datatype in MySQL? I have a table `Train` in which there are fields

```
trainno int
Weekdays set data type
Stops set data type
train name
```

How to write a select query where I can compare the `Stops` set with a particular value like `'Mumbai'`?

Comment: [Don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Comment: As an aside, please note that the SET type will not let you provide the list of stops with a particular order. Also, if for some reason the journey involves passing through (and stopping in) a particular place more than once, you won't be able to reflect that in your `Stops` column either.

Answer (score 1):

Create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE cl_db.Train
(
    trainno         INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Stops           set('aaa','bbb','ccc') NOT NULL
)
```

and you can query it like

```
select * from cl_db.Train where Stops like 'bbb'
```

or like

```
select * from cl_db.Train where FIND_IN_SET('bbb',Stops)>0;
```